# jQuery get css hover values

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

On page ready I want to run a function that will get the css background-image setting and also the hover background-image setting which I wish to then utilize in another fashion.

The only method I have seen to accomplish this requires someone to actually mouse over the element before you can get the value.

Anyone have a way?

This is how to get a css non-hover value:

```
$(this).css('background-color');
```

Comment: have you tried $("#"+this.id+":HOVER").css("background-color"); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you will need to read values from the stylesheet directly. The basic idea is to iterate through each stylesheet in `document.styleSheets`, and within these, iterate through each rule in `.cssRules` or `.rules`, looking for a `.selectorText` that matches what you're after.

To simplify things, I wrote a (tiny) library for this purpose - [JSS](https://github.com/Box9/jss). If you have a selector, for example `#someId:hover`, then using JSS, you can get its `background-color` property with:

```
jss('#someId:hover').get()['background-color']
```

Comment: jss fails the actually-does-something test, alas:  jss("#espacio_publico").get() ->
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null