# How to get css hover values on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, hover

Following up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265418/how-can-i-unbind-the-hover-opacity-effect-of-a-text-link-when-it-is-clicked), I have another issue - how to get css hover values when you click on a text link?

For instance, I have these values for the text hover

```
a.test {
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.test:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.6 !important;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)"; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=60) !important; 
}

<a href="#" class="test">Click Me</a>
```

this fails of course!

```
$(".test").click(function(){
   alert($(this).css());
   return false;
})
```

Is it possible?

I came across this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319472/jquery-get-css-hover-values) but I prefer not to use that plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this, where you create your own list of css properties that would be applied to that element (assuming you had a list) and then cycle through them:

```
var cssList = ['text-decoration','opacity','filter'];

$(".test").click(function(){
    for(x in cssList){
        alert($(this).css(cssList[x]));
    }    
   return false;
})
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/GmWCz/

Of course, you could take this all the way and add all the properties, if that is what you needed.

Comment: thanks. but how come it returns `none` for `filter:alpha(opacity=60) !important;`?

Answer (score 0):

HTML changes, adding an extra class:

```
<a href="" class="test apply-hover">Click Me</a>
```

CSS changes, modify hover selector:

```
a.test.apply-hover:hover { ...
```

JS changes, remove 'apply-hover' class on click event:

```
$(this).removeClass('apply-hover');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bGKE7/1/

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this seems like it would be to create a style tag and re-assign the hover property directly. I have a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bGKE7/2/).

(Credit where credit is due -- I got that from a function defined [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=129138))

Answer (score 0):

**[Take a look here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/css-with-no-arguments-should-return-a-object-of-style-attributes)**

It's a re-implementation (read: duck punching) of the `.css()` method

## [And here's the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tebvS/)